# GroupBy in F# and Average to values for each group

Tags: f#, group-by

I am a brand new to F#, and I am having trouble with a simple first query. I have a data set, and I want to group the dollar amount based on the codes (which repeat in the data). Then, for each group I want the average (and eventually standard deviation) of the dollar amounts for each group. Also, I only want to look at ONE providerID, hence the 'where' clause. From my research, I have gotten this far:

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()

let query2 = query { for x in dc.MyData do
                     groupBy x.Code into g
                     where (x.ProviderId = "some number of type string")
                     let average = query { for n in g do
                                           averageBy n.DollarAmt }
                     select (g.Key, average) }
System.Console.WriteLine(query2)
```

With this I get a compiling error that says, "The namespace or module 'x' is not defined."
I do not understand this because when I ran the query that only collected the data with the specified providerID, it did not complain about this 'x', and I followed the same format with this 'x' for this larger query.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: After the `groupBy` you can only access the group `g`, not the individual items `x`.  Try putting the `where` before the `groupBy`.

Comment: How would I pull back ALL the data with the averages tacked to the end of it, instead of only seeing the groups and their averages? Is that a simple syntax adjustment?

Comment: I'm all set on this now --- thanks!

Comment: @kvb You should post your comment as an answer so the OP can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

From @kvb's comment: After the `groupBy` you can only access the group `g`, not the individual items `x`. Try putting the `where` before the `groupBy`.